# Pagespeed image optimisation issue causing images not to display

Tags: image, pagespeed

I'm having a strange issue with pagespeed on the website I'm maintaining. Pagespeed has been set up and it works fine, except when it comes to images, then issues start to happen.

Lets say we have a image located and called:

```
<img src="/assets/images/car.png" alt="Car" />
```

Pagespeed will convert that to:

```
<img alt="Car" src="/assets/images/xcar.png.pagespeed.ic.3uWcepqUpW.webp" data-pagespeed-url-hash="585364661" onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);"
```

When it does this, the image stops displaying, when you clear the cache, the first load `/assets/images/car.png` displays in the source code and the image displays, refresh, it updates to `/assets/images/xcar.png.pagespeed.ic.3uWcepqUpW.webp` and the image doesn't display. But here is when it gets strange, other images using similar code work fine. I'm not sure what is going on here.

Here is the part of the pagespeed.conf:

```
ModPagespeedEnableFilters sprite_images
ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_images
ModPagespeedEnableFilters recompress_png
ModPagespeedEnableFilters convert_png_to_jpeg,convert_jpeg_to_webp
ModPagespeedEnableFilters extend_cache
ModPagespeedEnableFilters dedup_inlined_images
ModPagespeedEnableFilters insert_dns_prefetch
ModPagespeedEnableFilters strip_image_meta_data
ModPagespeedEnableFilters remove_quotes
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

You can try [ImageKit.io](https://imagekit.io) for optimizing images. It has everything PageSpeed has plus more. Do share your feedback.

Disclaimer - I am the co-founder.